# Remove Trailing Zero's getGrandTotal - Email Order Conformation

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I'm using this code here to pull in the total price

```
{{var store.getCurrentCurrencyCode()}}
{{if order.getGrandTotal()}}
  {{var order.getGrandTotal()}}
{{else}}
  0.00
{{/if}}
```

what I get as a price value in return is,
**32.9800**

adding two extra 00's at the end. How can I remove these? I'm using Magento 1.9 and this is my order confirmation email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to override Mage_Sales_Model_Order class and implement getFormattedGrandTotal, which should be called in place of getGrandTotal

```
public function getFormattedGrandTotal(){
    return number_format((float)$this->getGrandTotal(),2);
}
```

Comment: Wil this mess up my shopping cart system? because I'm only getting these duplicate numbers from my custom transactional email for order confirmation.  If I use the basic one there isn't a 00 at the end.

Comment: It will not if you implement new method for generating formatted Grand Total, and use that method only in your template.

Comment: You can pass formatted grand total as separate value to the template.

Comment: Where should I place the public function at?